# ESlint rule react/no-multi-comp does not detect multiple components using hooks in the same file

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I would like to allow only one React component per file in my project, so I tried to use the eslint rule react/no-multi-comp, however when I do ignoreStateless: true the rule is not detecting a hook-using component as a stateful component

`rules: {     'react/no-multi-comp': ['error', { ignoreStateless: true }],   }`

This is my full .eslintrc.js looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: ['airbnb-typescript', 'prettier', 'plugin:storybook/recommended'],
  plugins: ['import', 'react', 'react-hooks'],
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.eslint.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
  rules: {
    'react/no-multi-comp': ['error', { ignoreStateless: true }],
  },
};
```

I tried searching for other rules or threads regarding this rule not working for hooks using components but couldn't find any

Answer (score 0):

The `useState` hook, despite its name, isn't actually state on the component, and function components are still stateless.

See https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2481#issuecomment-548204987 for context.